# web3.js import error

Tags: spl-token, web3.js

import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from '/node_modules/@solana/web3.js';

The above line throwing the below error in my browser console. I am using plain html and javascript files to run this code.

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

---

That means I can't use simple html file to use any of solana blockchain end points.

May I know if Angular can be used?

Answer (score 2):

the error you got back is descriptive and it means you are trying to load the package using .html file extension whilst this package can only be loaded on a javascript application or framework.

I suggest you start trying out Svelte, React and the rest.

Comment: Yes you can use Angular and the best way to get started would be the Solana Cookbook.. [Solana CookBook Link](https://solanacookbook.com/getting-started/installation.html)

Comment: I have started implementaion on Angular but I am facing different issue now. I have installed Solana web3.js and just Import the web3.js at the top of my TS file.


"node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.d.ts:6:30 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'node-fetch'. 'C:/Code/DEMO/FullStack UI/FullStack.UI/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node-fetch` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'node-fetch';`

6   import * as nodeFetch from 'node-fetch';"

Comment: okay so to resolve this you can run `npm install node-fetch` in your terminal and after doing that you can import `node-fetch` using `import fetch from 'node-fetch';` .. this should resolve your issue...thanks

Comment: I have already tried but not succeded

Comment: okay then why not try this `npm i --save-dev @types/node-fetch` then import the `@solana/web3.js` afterwards

Answer (score 2):

You can import @solana/web3.js library into a plain HTML file via script tag.

```
<!-- Development (un-minified) -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.js"></script>

<!-- Production (minified) -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>
```

To connect to `devnet` cluster:

```
const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
```

Note: It is **solanaWeb3** and not **web3**